# Slide Feature: setProperty not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css-variables

I'm working on a slide feature and it works great on all browsers except IE of course.

I firstly thought it's because of `Math.sign` but I've added a polyfill for it and it solve the error, but the slider still didn't work. Then I investigated a bit more and I think it's because of this syntax

```
_C.style.setProperty('--i', num);
```

which is used to set a value and use it in CSS like this:

```
transform: translate(calc(var(--i, 0)/var(--n)*var(--n)*-100%));
```

```
function move(e) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('checked')[0].classList.remove('checked')
  if(x0 || x0 === 0) {
    if (!Math.sign) {
      Math.sign = function(x) {
        return ((x > 0) - (x < 0)) || +x;
    }
  }
    let dx = unify(e).clientX - x0, s = Math.sign(dx);

    if((i > 0 || s < 0) && (i < N - 1 || s > 0))
      _C.style.setProperty('--i', i -= s);
      let circles = document.getElementsByClassName('testimonial-circle')
      let circle = circles[i]
      circle.classList.add('checked')

    x0 = null
  }
};
```

The idea is to click on a bubble and slide to the specific "testimonial"

Comment: Take a look at the console, read the error messages ...

Comment: No errors, @Teemu :D

Comment: Perhaps a CSS warning then? As a sidenote, IE doesn't support block context for variables, even they're declared with `let`. Most likely not an issue here, but it's good to know, that `let` is exactly the same as `var` in IE.

Comment: Nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: @Teemu ahh good to know, thanks

Comment: What is `_C`? I don't recall such style property as `--i`, do you use it to set some value and read it somewhere else?

Comment: @barbsan _C is an element ( bad naming) I edited my question to answer your second question

Comment: Take a look at CSS `var` support in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Or even better look at this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Try to use Transform with vendor prefix may help to solve the issue. https://i.postimg.cc/tRtdXwJJ/108.png Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform